# Change classic site to modern expereince

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-team-site

I know how to change a document library from classic to modern experience and vise-versa.

In case the sharepoint site has been created in classic experience, is it possible to change the sharepoint site to modern experience?

If this is possible can you provide any article or link on how to do this.

Once you switch your entire sharepoint site to modern is it possible to go back to classic?

Answer (score 1):

To change a document library from classic to modern experience.

Go to library settings->advanced settings->scroll down, “List experience” section, select “New experience” for “Display this list using the new or classic experience?”.

[image]

To change the SharePoint site from classic experience to modern experience, we can connect the classic SharePoint site to office 365 group.

Go to Gear->select “connect to new office 365 group”.

Then it will create a modern home page for the classic site collection.

[image]

It is possible to go back to classic experience after switching the site to modern experience. 
You could go to the site pages library and click the original home page.

Updated:

The Home.aspx is the original home page.

The Home(1).aspx is the modern home page for the classic site collection.

[image]

Comment: can you show a screenshot of  "click the original home page" ?

Comment: i have updated the reply.

Comment: Once you click “connect to new office 365 group”.. Does that mean  new new modern home page is created or the current ones is switched to modern ? and If I switched to modern and now I want to go back to classic one I just have to click "Home.aspx" ? (how does the stiching back happen) . sorry so many questions Im just no sure. thank you @Amy_MSFT